# Set attribute on a project at creation with API

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm attempting to set an attribute via the Acumatica API. I run the code the project is created but the attribute is not added/updated on the project. The code does not throw an error.

```cs
using (var soapClient = new DefaultSoapClient())
{
    //Log in to Acumatica ERP
    soapClient.Login();

    Project projectToBeCreated = new Project
    {
        ProjectID = new StringValue { Value = "<NEW>" },
        //ProjectTemplateID = new StringValue { Value = "Event" },
        Customer = new StringValue { Value = "0000027"},
        Description = new StringValue { Value = "Matts TESTINGUPDATE!" },

        Attributes = new []
        {
            new AttributeValue
            {
                AttributeID = new StringValue {Value="EVTID" },
                Required = new BooleanValue {Value = false},
                Value = new StringValue {Value ="Event TEST"}

            }
        }

    };

    Project projectData = (Project)soapClient.Put(projectToBeCreated);
    soapClient.Logout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out after discussing with Acumatica Vendor. It appears that you do not use the Attribute ID when setting this through the API. Instead you need to put the Attribute Description that was set at attribute creation. Corrected code is below.

```
    Attributes = new []
    {
        new AttributeValue
        {
            AttributeID = new StringValue {Value="EXTERNAL EVENT ID" },
            Required = new BooleanValue {Value = false},
            Value = new StringValue {Value ="Event TEST"}

        }
    }
```